# Integrate aws websocket api with springboot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, websocket

**I have created realtime activities website.

currently my website is like this:

frontend page created websocket with endpoint url wss://xyz.com/chat/$scope.userId

In my backend i store a map table of userId-Websocketconnection

when anyone likes image of userId-5 , backend sends notification to websocketConnection whose userId is 5

**But now i want to use Aws websocket api**
i am confused at several points

1. how to send userId with websocket connection request to aws websocket api
2. using aws websocket api ,how can i store this connectionid and user id in my springboot database
3. when someone likes image of userId-5 , how will i send notification to websocket connection of userId-5
   Is it possible using aws websocket api. Please help me

**

Answer (score 0):

That's what exactly APIGateway websocket protocol offers.

1. You need to connect to websocket, then send a message (json) which has userid in it.  Example message below.

   {"action": "SUBSCRIBE","payload": {"userId":"123"}}
2. On APIGateway you can create SUBSCIRBE route and map it to backend endpoint as Integration request where you store connection id into database.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-integration-requests.html
3. Whenever your spring boot application wants to push notifications, you can make use of `AmazonApiGatewayManagementApi` and broadcast the message.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html